# Почему нельзя складывать указатели?

Tags: указатели, c++

На экзамене задали вопрос:

**Почему нельзя складывать указатели?**

Разность между указателями возвращает число элементов между указателями, т.е. число. Логично было предположить, что и сумма должна возвращать некое число, но оказалось, что сложение указателей не определено. Интересует причина.

Comment: Последствия встречи Нового Года? А что Вы получите в результате сложения указателей, т.е. каков смысл такой операции?

Comment: А что Вы хотите получить в результате сложения? Значение указателя – это адрес. Вот есть адрес «улица Ростостовская дом № 13 квартира № 18» и адрес «улица Кирова дом № 43 квартира № 12». Попробуйте сложить. Что хотите получить в результате? Воскресенье? Булки с гвоздями? Зелёный? Кислый? Вычитание хоть как-то осмысленно: разность указателей равна расстоянию между ячейками, на которые они указывают. А сумма?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Никто складывать не запрещает, разве что может компилятор будет warning выкидывать. Другой вопрос - нафиг оно надо.

Приведу пример их жизни. На проводах категории 5e (интернетовых) очень часто пишут "указатель", т.е. число, которое каждый метр увеличивается. Вот есть у нас сколько-то метров такого провода. В начале написана метка `185m`, через ровно 1 метр будет метка `186m` и так далее. Мы знаем, что на другом конце метка `211m`.

Вычтем указатели 211-185 = 26. Получается у нас всего 26 метров такого провода. Вычитание указателей на практике используется для того, чтобы узнать сколько между этими указателями "места", или в нашем случае провода. И важно одно свойство - со скольких бы мы не начинали отсчёт, всё равно получим 26 метров. Существование меток вне диапазона, например `10m` или `500m` нам не важно.

Теперь сложим: 211+185 = 396. Полученое число не несёт ни какой смысловой нагрузки. Причём оно указывает на метку, которой не существует (катушки обычно по 305 метров)

Comment: Да? И как же определить оператор, смысл операции которого не известен? Напишите перегрузку оператора для <pre><code>operator + (void *p1, void *p2)</code></pre>.

Answer (score 15):

Петя живет в доме №5, Вася в доме №9. Разность этих чисел нам может сказать например как далеко они друг от друга живут (будем считать, что дома физически расположены линейно). А что нам дает сумма номеров домов? **ничего**.

Подобным образом бессмысленно складывать например две даты - мы можем только к дате прибавить какой-то интервал времени, или вычитая из одной даты другую получить как раз таки интервал.

Answer (score 9):

[[@PewX2](/users/16658/pewx2)](/users/16658/pewx2) Попробуйте объяснить "физический" смысл сложения указателей. Ну вычитание указателей можно изобразить на схеме

```
-----+-----+--------
     ^     ^
     |-----|
    p1    p2
```

На той же схеме можно изобразить вычитание числа из указателя, сложение числа и указателя (операции индексации). Попробуйте изобразить сложение указателей.

(Кстати, адрес 0 на схеме не видно, и где он находится, никто не знает)

А что в результате получится число -- так это да. Приводите указатели к unsigned int и складывайте. Только что с этим числом потом делать?

Answer (score 6):

Есть дорога. На ней верстовые столбы, на каждом столбе написано, сколько вёрст до этого столба от некоего нулевого столба.

Доехали мы до столба № 306. До него от нулевого столба в идеальном случае ровно 326 440,8 метра. А наш друг отстал по той же дороге и доехал до столба №298, до того столба от нулевого столба ровно 317 906,4 метров.

Если вычесть одного из другого, то получим, что друг отстал на 8 вёрст = 8 534,4 метра. Это имеет смысл. Если нулевой столб поставить в другом месте, то наш столб будет № 474 и до него будет 505 663,2 метров, а столб друга будет № 466 и до него будет 497 128,8. Но между ними всё равно 8 вёрст и всё равно 8 534,4 метра. Так и должно быть, так как это те же самые места и по-прежнему на одной дороге.

А каков смысл суммы? 306+298=604, 474+466=940. Ладно, пусть столб № 940 существует. Вот только нам он не интересен. А почему? Да потому, что это вообще не номер столба. Вычтем одну сумму из другой: 940-604=336. А что это такое? Можно начать номера не с № 0, а с № 168, но расположить столб № 168 не в другом, а в том же месте, тогда наш столб тоже будет № 474, а столб друга будет № 466 и между ними будет 8 вёрст или 8 534,4 метра. Так и должно быть. А что такое 336? Это 168*2, то есть **двойной номер начального столба**. Мы вроде складывали два числа, а в сумму вошло третье число, да ещё и дважды. А ведь номер начального столба имеет самостоятельный смысл только при его поиске, сумма не равна 168, соответственно, мы начальный столб не ищем.

Номера остальных столбов имеют самостоятельный смысл только при их поиске, а разность номеров заменяет нам гигантскую измерительную рулетку для измерения расстояний между столбами, между номерами которых и вычисляется разность.

А какой смысл в двойном номере?

Есть два друга. Вася и Петя. Есть некий словарь, в котором перечислены все сочетания по четыре буквы, для каждого сочетания написан его смысл, а для имён – сколько лет человеку, какого он пола, где живёт и хулиган он, или дружинник. Про некоторые сочетания написано «такого слова не существует». Адрес, по которому записан смысл слова, – это значение указателя. Пусть указатель на сочетание xyzt равен code(t)+code(z)*33+code(y)*33*33+code(x)*33*33*33, где code – функция, возвращающая код буквы. Петя-Вася=5492, не зависимо от того, равны ли коды букв их номерам в русском алфавите, или больше на некоторую величину из-за того, что начало кодой таблицы зарезервировано для других символов. Важно, что буквы также упорядочены. И это значение показывает, сколько между ними словарных статей, считая со статьёй про Петю. Если стоят другие множители, то сами словарные статьи расположены на другом расстоянии, но разность всё равно покажет количество статей между ними, считая со статьёй про Петю. Если буквы иначе упорядочены, то и тогда разность покажет количество статей между ними, считая со статьёй про одного из них. Если и буквы иначе упорядочены, и множители другие, то и тогда разность равна количеству статей между ними, считая со статьёй про одного из них. Даже если в словаре не все сочетания, а адреса статей не вычисляются, а просто запомнены в указателях, то даже тогда разность покажет количество статей между ними, считая со статьёй про одного из них. А сумма? Что такое Петя+Вася? Это не числа и у нас нет даже алфавитного порядка букв, так как система пронумеровала их как хотела. Более того. Мы могли бы записать имена иероглифами, тогда какого-то определённого порядка символов вообще не было бы в отрыве от конкретной кодировки, а кодировка в случае указателя известна только операционной системе, да ещё и может меняться от слова к слову. И что тогда такое ピーター+ヴァシャ? ピーター-ヴァシャвсё равно покажет количество словарных статей между ними, считая со статьёй про одного из них. А сложить иероглифы не сможет даже японец.

Comment: ИМХО, очень много букв, можно было и короче :), но это мое естественно частное мнение. За работу "+".

Comment: представьте что они оба грузопереревозчики и Вы обоим должны заплатить, у вас оплата за версту 1 рубль, как посчитать сколько Вам нужно им заплатить?

Answer (score 1):

Представьте себе направленную прямую (ось). На этой оси можно ставить точки и откладывать векторы. Точка - аналог указателя. Векторы же одномерные, т.е. имеют всего одну координату, так что каждый такой вектор можно считать просто числом.

Разность двух точек - это вектор. Сумма точки и вектора - точка. Разность точки и вектора - тоже точка.

А что такое сумма двух точек?

Comment: если операция определена на множестве, зачем искать в этом смысл?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а разве она определена?

Comment: сложение чисел?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ сложение точек

Comment: в одномерном пространстве точка представлена одним числом, или мы о разных точках говорим?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нарисуйте на листочке бумаги точку. Какое число вы видите?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ для того, чтобы представить точку числом, вам нужна система координат, состоящая из базиса и начала отсчета. Применительно к указателям, базис у вас есть, а вот начала отсчёта как-то не завезли.

Comment: память это массив (упрощенно) ячейка 0, имеет указатель 0, разве нет?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в стандарте языка нет такого требования

Comment: зато в аппаратуре есть

Comment: @StrangerintheQ где вы "в аппаратуре" видели указатели?

Comment: про VHDL слышали?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ мы, кажется, С++ обсуждаем, а не VHDL

Comment: вы приводите оторванный от c++ пример.., я не спорю что в с++ сложение значений указателей не имеет смысла, я больше про Вашу аналогию с точками и векторами

Comment: @StrangerintheQ указатели и числа в C++ образуют подобие аффинного пространства, только над кольцом вместо поля. Я привёл другое аффинное пространство, которое будет более понятным незнакомому с математикой читателю.

Answer (score -1):

Только начинаю изучение C и как-то захотелось сложить адреса для функции swap где я бы просто поменял адреса к объектам которые я хочу свапнуть не создавая лишней переменной)))
Но понял что адрес памяти в аргументе функции не ссылка на ссылку)
Сильно не ругайте пришел с Java

```
void swap(void* a, void* b) {
  a += b;
  b = a - b;
  a = a - b;
}
```

В общем это ответ на вопрос зачем бы пригодилось их сложить, вне функции например)

**А почему нельзя, тут скорей всего разработчики языка хотели исключить возможность выхода из области памяти, так как при сложении двух указателей это происходит в 99% случаев операция не имеет смысла**

Answer (score -3):

```
typedef unsigned char byte; //instead char may use long long...

byte * add_pointers(byte * pointer, byte * offset) {
    byte * max_byte = (byte *)(~((byte)0));
    while (offset > max_byte) {
        pointer = pointer + (~((byte)0));
        offset = offset - (~((byte)0));
    }
    return pointer + (byte)offset;
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы признателен вам за экспертный комментарий и пояснение предложенного решения.